# Pod install Firebase/Analytics fails

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, cocoapods, firebase-analytics

I'm using Window 10 and trying to use Pod to integrate `Firebase/Analytics` with `flutter` and everything seems fine except I'm getting this error when I run `pod install`

Here is the `stackTrace`

```
 

    CocoaPods : 1.9.3
            Ruby : ruby 2.6.6p146 (2020-03-31 revision 67876) [x64-mingw32]
        RubyGems : 3.0.3
            Host : Unable to find an executable (No such file or directory - sw_vers)  ()
           Xcode : -version) ()
             Git : git version 2.27.0.windows.1
    Ruby lib dir : F:/Ruby26-x64/lib
    Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

And this is my `Pod` file

```rb
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Runner' do
  
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  # Pods for Runner


end

  # add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  # add pods for any other desired Firebase products
  # https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods
```

The `podfile` is inside the `ios` folder of my `flutter` project

Can you help me solve this?

Comment: you don't need to touch the Podfile and AppDelegate when integrating firebase to flutter for ios. You just need to add the GoogleService-Info.plist file inside Xcode. The instructions you followed is for Native iOS setup. [reference](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1944#issuecomment-584482375).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the pod repo. So try the following command from command line.

```
pod repo update
```

If the error still there then you may need to upgrade the cocoa pods.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

I was facing the same error while integrating firebase storage in my flutter project. I did `pod repo update` and the issue gone.

**Edit:**

If you manually added firebase analytics pod in pod file then just remove it.

You need to add dependancy in .yaml file in flutter project.

```
dependencies:
  firebase_analytics: ^6.0.0
```

Check [here](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics/install) for more details.

**NOTE: While working on flutter project you do not need to install any library using pod(iOS) or gradle(android) unless very specific requirement.**

IF there is any specific platform requirement then you need to add pod file for iOS project like below...

You need to write the line pod 'Firebase/Analytics' inside target 'Runner' do...end block like below...

```
 # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '10.0'

 target 'Runner' do

    # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
   use_frameworks!

    # Pods for Runner

  # add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

end
```

Comment: I got this error (see the completion in the next comment I can't post here because comment limitaions)

``Updating spec repo `cocoapods`
  $ C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe -C C:/Users/H.Abbas/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods fetch origin --progress
  remote: Enumerating objects: 27, done.
  remote: Counting objects: 100% (27/27), done.
  remote: Compressing objects: 100% (17/17), done.
  remote: Total 18 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
  From https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs
     c5b0d40f05b1..98ceea0f4d61  master     -> origin/master``

Comment: $ C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe -C C:/Users/H.Abbas/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
  master
  $ C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe -C C:/Users/H.Abbas/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods reset --hard origin/master
  error: invalid path 'Specs/c/f/f/XCActionSheet./0.0.2/XCActionSheet..podspec.json'
  fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'origin/master'.

Comment: Yes! I added the ``Firebase/Analtytics`` to it from the Firebase website

Answer (score 0):

pod 'Firebase/Analytics' should be added before the "end" keyword. Currently you have added it after the "end" keyword.
Hope my answer will resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Your pod must between `target` and `end` keyword.

```
target 'Runner' do
      
    //Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!
      pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

end
```